# Invalid port in python sockets

Tags: python, windows, sockets, icmp

I am getting error while trying to send bare ICMP message using following snippet:

Windows says this port is invalid for given IP range.

```
def send_ping(source_ip,target_ip,data_function=construct_icmp_echo):
    fail = 0
    skt_send = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_RAW,socket.IPPROTO_ICMP)
    skt_recv = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_RAW,socket.IPPROTO_ICMP)
    (src_binary,) = struct.unpack (">L",socket.inet_aton(source_ip))
    (tgt_binary,) = struct.unpack (">L",socket.inet_aton(source_ip))

    skt_send.setsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, socket.IP_TTL, 16)
    ipheader = struct.pack("BBHHHBBHLL",0x54,0xdc,48,50,8,16,1,0,src_binary,tgt_binary)
    cksum = icmpcksum(ipheader)
    ipheader = ipheader = struct.pack("BBHHHBBHLL",0x54,0xdc,48,50,8,16,1,cksum,src_binary,tgt_binary)
    skt_send.sendto(data_function(),(target_ip,22433))
    skt_recv.bind((target_ip,22433))
    skt_recv.settimeout(5)
    thetime = datetime.datetime.now()
    try: 
        s = datetime.datetime.now()
        while time.time - s < 60:
            a = skt_recv.recvfrom(1024)[0]
            hdr_reply = a[20:]
            icmp_type = a[20]
            if icmp_type == 0 :
                print ("got a ping")
                fl = True
                return target_ip
            if fl: break
    except socket.timeout as e:
        raise e
    return
```

here: 
`skt.recv_bind((target_ip,22433))`
IP address I have fed are B- and C-class IP addresses.

I get this traceback:

```
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensio
ns\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.2\visualstudio_py_launcher.py", li
ne 78, in <module>
    vspd.debug(filename, port_num, debug_id, debug_options, run_as)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensio
ns\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.2\visualstudio_py_debugger.py", li
ne 2465, in debug
    exec_file(file, globals_obj)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensio
ns\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.2\visualstudio_py_util.py", line 1
11, in exec_file
    exec_code(code, file, global_variables)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensio
ns\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.2\visualstudio_py_util.py", line 8
7, in exec_code
    exec(code_obj, global_variables)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\python-ipscan\python
-ipscan\python_ipscan.py", line 86, in <module>
    if __name__=="__main__": main ()
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\python-ipscan\python
-ipscan\python_ipscan.py", line 83, in main
    send_ping (myaddr,"""155.223.197.1""",construct_icmp_echo)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\python-ipscan\python
-ipscan\python_ipscan.py", line 70, in send_ping
    traceback.print_stack()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\python-ipscan\python
-ipscan\python_ipscan.py", line 86, in <module>
    if __name__=="__main__": main ()
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\python-ipscan\python
-ipscan\python_ipscan.py", line 84, in main
    traceback.extract_tb(sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python34\lib\traceback.py", line 106, in extract_tb
    return list(_extract_tb_iter(tb, limit=limit))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python34\lib\traceback.py", line 59, in _extract_tb_or_
stack_iter
    f, lineno, next_item = extractor(curr)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'tb_frame'
```

Exception when not handled by user code:
`OSError was unhandled by user code
Message: [WinError 10049] Invalid request for given address`

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to send to port 22433 before the receiving socket has bound the port. The `skt_send.sendto()` call is therefore trying to send to a non-existent endpoint - at the time of that call there's nothing listening on port 22433. Try putting the `skt_recv.bind()` call before it.

It would be helpful to see the traceback given by the interpreter, as with only a vague description of the error we have to guess what went wrong.

Comment: Did not help. Traceback added.

Comment: It looks like you are calling the traceback manually rather than just letting an exception happen. The error currently reported appears to be nothing to do with networking at all, but rather due to an incorrect traceback call. It certainly isn't the error you report about an invalid port number. Didn't the program produce an exception traceback?

Comment: I did not realise it will matter to produce a different traceback when called manually.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make myself clear. It appeared to me, from reading the traceback you posted (thanks, btw) that you had made an edit to your program so that it was making a call to `traceback.print_stack()`. When I asked for the traceback I assumed (because you said "Windows says this port is invalid for given IP range") that your program was producing a Python exception traceback.

Comment: What is the exact message you see? Does it appear in a terminal window or as a Windows alert?

Comment: I notice on further examination that you are talking to an external (i.e. another computers') IP address. It seems possible the message is coming from your firewall. If that is the case we should delete this question. I hope it is, as then at least your problem will be solved.

Comment: VS debugger was attached, I do not know how to get traceback in that scemario

Comment: I could see exception explanation and unwindling but no traceback.

Comment: This thread's discussion was moved to chat. That discussion has now been deleted.